# Pass argument to a function containing dplyr piped expression group_by with stringr::str_extract

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rlang

I would like to summarise the following data by groups based on substrings:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~sometext, ~somevalue,
  "Kardiochirurgia",  120,
  "Kardiologia",      240,
  "Ortopedia onkologiczna",        120,
  "Kardiochirurgia onkologiczna", 300,
  "Ortopedia i traumatologia",110,
  "Urologia", 80
)
```

Here are my substrings I would like to group by:

```
categories <- c("kardio","orto", "uro")
```

The following code works and I will use it repeatedly, so I would like to turn it into a function:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(categories=
    str_extract(
      string = str_to_lower(.$sometext),
      pattern = paste0(categories, collapse="|"))) %>% 
  summarise(somevalue = sum(somevalue))
```

The script returns exactly what I expected:

```
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
# categories somevalue
# <chr>          <dbl>
# 1 kardio           660
# 2 orto             230
# 3 uro               80
```

After I turned it into a function, it does not work:

```
group_by_str <- function(df, strings, patterns) {
  df %>% 
    group_by(categories=
               str_extract(
                 string = str_to_lower(.[,{{strings}}]),
                 pattern = paste0(patterns, collapse="|"))) 
   return(df)
}
```

The double bracketed strings is one of my attempts, i tried first without, tried passing quoted name etc. to no avail .
Trying to use it on a dataset:

```
df %>% group_by_str(strings=sometext, patterns= categories) %>% summarise(somevalue = sum(somevalue))
```

returns an error, obviously it does not know that 'strings' is the name of the column containing strings. What should be the correct way of passing a column name to a function in this case?

Error message indicates R can see the content of the column and attempts to treat it as column names :

```
 Error: Can't find columns `Kardiochirurgia`, `Kardiologia`, `Ortopedia onkologiczna`, `Kardiochirurgia onkologiczna`, `Ortopedia i traumatologia`, … (and 1 more) in `.data`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

If I remove the curly curly brackets the error says R does not see the `sometext` column name present in the DF:

```
Error in check_names_df(j, x) : object 'sometext' not found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With some modifications, we can use the following code.

1. We do not need to evaluate `patterns`(added this point because I thought of `tidy` `eval`uating `patterns` too).
2. We can evaluate `strings` with `{{}}` with `rlang` [>=0.4.0](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rlang/news/news.html).
3. We do not need a `return` statement
4. We can do everything(including the summarise) inside our function

Modified code:

```
group_by_str <- function(df, strings, patterns) {
  df %>% 
    group_by(categories=
               str_extract(
                 string = str_to_lower({{strings}}),
                 pattern = paste0(patterns, 
                                          collapse="|"))) %>%

    summarise(somevalue = sum(somevalue)) 

} 


  group_by_str(df,strings=sometext, patterns= categories)
```

Pipe friendly:

```
 df %>% 
  group_by_str(strings=sometext, patterns= categories)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  categories somevalue
  <chr>          <dbl>
1 kardio           660
2 orto             230
3 uro               80
```

Comment: Is there rlang 1.0.0?  - I would like to smuggle here big thank you for help.

Comment: Ah, oh nooo! I mistook the version with that of `tidyr`. It's in fact `rlang` 0.4.2. The `{{}}` "trick" was introduced in 0.4.0.